# Execute actions both sync and async

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous

In laravel 5.7 I want to be able to have multiple actions,
for example inserting user in database, sending registration Email,
sending notification, ...
I want to be able to execute these actions both sync and async.
the problem is I don't want to create Job class for every action.
each action is a php callable class.
The thing I don't understand in Laravel Job class is It receives dependencies as handle method arguments and receive It's Input which should process on,in the constructor, I think It's kind of odd.

for example when I want to call send register email action, I want to be able to do sth like :

```
$registerEmailAction->__invoke($user, true);
```

second parameter indicates whether to do this action sync or async.

Comment: I don't understand the question very well. How are you handling async jobs? Why not use Queues for this?

Comment: I don't mind using queues, but as I said I have many (40) php callable class which I call them my actions, and what I need, is to be able to call these actions synchronously or asynchronous, and I don't want create 40 new classes just to be able to handle async in my code base.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Job classes are simple objects that only need to implement the `ShouldQueue` interface and an `handle()` method. You can dispatch them, or run them immediately explicitly calling the handle method. If you want to take the `__invoke` route you could so something like this:

```
class RegisterEmailAction implements ShouldQueue
{
    //... more code ...

    public function __invoke(User $user, bool $async)
    {
        $this->setUser($user);
        if ($async) {
            dispatch($this);
        }
        else {
            $this->handle(); // or dispatch_now($this);
        }
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        if (!$this->user) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException();
    }
        //  ... some other code ...
    }
}
```

Since you don't want to pass the $user as a dependency in the constructor, I would suggest to check for it in the handle method, so that you get an error if some client code tries to call the handle method, without taking the `__invoke` route. You also may needs to use some traits, like `SerializeeModels` or `Dispatchable` (check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues) for more info).